# How to make sure users know a photo is clickable?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

On our new home page, we are placing a couple of photos with a title in the lower portion of the photo.  These photos are hyperlinks into the two main topic areas of our site.

We're looking for ideas of how best to indicate to users that they can click these.  In the old days, we might just make them a 3D button.  But in today's flat is everything world, I'm not sure a subtle shadow would be enough.

What are some suggestions that have worked well for you?  An arrow on the image? bevel the image to look like a button? a greater than arrow? a turned down corner signaling a page that can be turned? a button on the button with a call to action such as "read more" or "click here" or ???

Comment: tiles and modern UI https://metroui.org.ua/templates/start-screen.html

Answer (score 0):

The [pointer cursor](http://fingercursor.com/images/finger_big.jpg) is, as far as I know, the universal "click this" symbol:

```
// CSS
img:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can also add a "read more/see more" item that appears on hover (or not) as you mentioned in your original post.